# fetal error: path not found

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Hi Guys I'm working on a MVC based php application.In my include.php which is also in the server root of my server has following codes in order to fetch model and controller automatically from Controller folder inside the application directory of the server root.

My project directory is like this

```
accountBook
|-Application
|       |-Controller
|       |     |-IndexController.php
|       |     |-baseController.php
|       |_-Model
|-Content
|-index.php
|-config.php
|-includes.php
```

```html
<?php
/*
 *@Package Name: accountBook/includes.php
 *@Date(Last Modified): Thru, Sept 15 - 2016
 *@Author: Ajax Hill
 */

namespace accountBook
{
    use accountBook\Application\Controller;
    class accessControl
    {
        private $args,$type,$nature;
        private static function route()
        {
            define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
            define('ROOT',getcwd().DS);
            define('CONF', ROOT.'config.php');
            include_once(CONF);
            $con= new PDO;
            if($result=$con->query('SELECT theme from sys_def'))
            {
                while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                {
                    define('THEME_NAME',$row['theme']);
                }
            }
            else
            {    
                echo "ERROR: Could not execute".print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
            }
            /*
             * @var THEME_NAME(view) has been Fetch from Database
             */
            define('CONTENT', ROOT.'content'.DS);
            define('THEME_PATH',CONTENT.'themes'.DS.THEME_NAME.DS);
            define('APP',ROOT.'Application'.DS);
            define('CONTROL_PATH',APP.'contollers'.DS);
            define('MODEL_PATH',APP.'models'.DS);
            
            // index.php?p=admin&c=Goods&a=add
            define("PLATFORM", isset($_REQUEST['p']) ? $_REQUEST['p'] : 'home');
            define("CONTROLLER", isset($_REQUEST['c']) ? $_REQUEST['c'] : 'Index');
            define("ACTION", isset($_REQUEST['a']) ? $_REQUEST['a'] : 'index');

           unset($con);
        }
        // Autoloading

        private static function autoload()
        {
              // Controller
                require_once CONTROL_PATH. "{$classname}.php";
            } 
            elseif (substr($classname, -5) == "Model")
            {
                // Model
                require_once  MODEL_PATH . "{$classname}.php";
            }
        }
        // Routing and dispatching

        private static function dispatch()
        {
            // Instantiate the controller class and call its action method
            
            $controller_name = CONTROLLER . "Controller";
            $action_name = ACTION . "Action";
            $controller = new $controller_name;
            $controller->$action_name();

        }
        public function __construct($type, $args,$nature='show')
        /**
         * var @type has two values = account | toDo
         * var @type is post title
         * var @nature is to determine the nature
         */
        {
            $this->args=$args;
            $this->type=$type;
            $this->nature=$nature;
            self::route();
            self::autoload();
            self::dispatch();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I've create IndexController.php in Application folder

```html
<?php
/**
 *@Package Name: accountBook/Application/Controller/IndexController.php
 *@Date(Last Modified): Thru, Sept 15 - 2016
 *@Author: Ajax Hill
 */
namespace accountBook\Application\controller;
class IndexController extends baseController
{
    public function mainAction(){

        include THEME_PATH. "main.html";

        // Load Captcha class

        $this->loader->library("Captcha");

        $captcha = new Captcha;

        $captcha->hello();

        $userModel = new UserModel("user");

        $users = $userModel->getUsers();

    }

    public function indexAction(){

                       $userModel = new UserModel("user");

        $users = $userModel->getUsers();

        // Load View template

        include  THEME_PATH . "index.php";

    }

    public function menuAction(){

        include THEME_PATH . "menu.php";

    }

    public function dragAction(){

        include THEME_PATH . "drag.php";

    }

    public function topAction(){

        include THEME_PATH . "top.php";

    }

}
```

When Loading index file which has included includes.php I'm getting Following error

```
fetal error at line 67 not found path c://phpproj/accountBook/Application/Controller/accountBook/Application/Controller/baseController.php
```

Now Please help me adjust so that baseController fetch from c://phpproj/accountBook/Application/Controller/baseController.php

Answer (score 0):

Your Class should have read something like:

```
<?php
    /*
     *@Package Name: accountBook/includes.php
     *@Date(Last Modified): Thru, Sept 15 - 2016
     *@Author: Ajax Hill
     */

    namespace accountBook;
    use accountBook\Application\Controller;

    class accessControl {
        private $args,$type,$nature;

        private static function route(){
            define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
            define('ROOT',getcwd().DS);
            define('CONF', ROOT.'config.php');
            include_once(CONF);
            $con= new PDO;
            if($result=$con->query('SELECT theme from sys_def')) {
                while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    define('THEME_NAME',$row['theme']);
                }
            }else{
                echo "ERROR: Could not execute".print_r($pdo->errorInfo());
            }

            /*
             * @var THEME_NAME(view) has been Fetch from Database
             */
            define('CONTENT', ROOT.'content'.DS);
            define('THEME_PATH',CONTENT.'themes'.DS.THEME_NAME.DS);
            define('APP',ROOT.'Application'.DS);
            define('CONTROL_PATH',APP.'contollers'.DS);
            define('MODEL_PATH',APP.'models'.DS);

            // index.php?p=admin&c=Goods&a=add
            define("PLATFORM", isset($_REQUEST['p']) ? $_REQUEST['p'] : 'home');
            define("CONTROLLER", isset($_REQUEST['c']) ? $_REQUEST['c'] : 'Index');
            define("ACTION", isset($_REQUEST['a']) ? $_REQUEST['a'] : 'index');

            unset($con);
        }

        // Autoloading  
        private static function autoload(){
            $classname     = algorithm_2_get_className();
            if(substr($classname, -10) == "Controller"){
                // Controller
                $classFile = CONTROL_PATH . "{$classname}.php";
            }else if (substr($classname, -5) == "Model"){
                // Model
                $classFile =   MODEL_PATH . "{$classname}.php";
            }

            if(file_exists($classFile){
                require_once $classFile;
            }else{
                // HANDLE FILE-NOT FOUND EXCEPTION...
            }
        }

        // Routing and dispatching
        private static function dispatch(){ 
            // Instantiate the controller class and call its action method

            $controller_name = CONTROLLER . "Controller";
            $action_name = ACTION . "Action";
            $controller = new $controller_name;
            $controller->$action_name();

        }

        public function __construct($type, $args,$nature='show'){
            /**
             * var @type has two values = account | toDo
             * var @type is post title
             * var @nature is to determine the nature
             */
            $this->args=$args;
            $this->type=$type;
            $this->nature=$nature;
            self::route();
            self::autoload();
            self::dispatch();
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok! I'll try this when I'll be at home.I'll let you know about it tommorow